# How to have “My Cart” in banner7.phtml? how to show everything same like in header My cart

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, programming

i have installed magento 1.8.1 and i want to show My Cart right after banner section. i am placing the code in banner.phtml file and it seems working but problem is that it is not showing cart items and cost etc stuff. can any one please share some universal code that can be used anywhere in .phtml file. my source code is below:

```
<div class="slider-mycart">
<div class="block block-verticalmenu">
<div>
    <div class="block-cart">
        <?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
        <!--<span class="top-cart-icon"></span>-->
        <span>
            <!--<span>Shopping Cart</span><br/>-->
            <?php echo $this->__('My Cart') ?>: <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?></span>
        <div class="top-cart-content">
            <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
            <?php if(count($_items)): ?>
                <ol id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list">
                <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('cart-sidebar', 'none-recursive')</script>
            <?php else: ?>
                <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php if($_cartQty && $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()): ?>
            <div class="actions">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_actions') ?>
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
            </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just copy code from one phtml file to another and expect it to work. All phtml files are loaded within some block class context so every function like `$this->getRecentItems()` is referncing the class that included the phtml file. In your case banner template file does not have methods that will build cart items collection. The proper way to do this is using xml files in layout folder. You need to define child block for the block that uses your banner template and call that block with `$this->getChildHtml()` function in banner phtml file.
You can start by reading some of the knowledge base on magento site:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts